# Select based on Many to one relationship criteria - Spring Data

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

For the following entities,

```
public class Book {

    private String bookName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "name", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Author> authors;

}

public class Author {

    private String name;
    private String location;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "bookName", referencedColumnName = "bookName")
    private Book book;

}
```

If I want to retrieve the list of books whose **authors** are located in **USA** for example.

```
@Query("SELECT a from Book a, Author b where b.location = "USA")
```

But, the following query retrieves only the books whose **authors** are in **USA** but not only the **authors** with location **USA** but **authors** with other locations too.

How do i only want to retrieve the books along with their **authors** who are located in **USA** and filter out the authors who are not from **USA**.

Comment: have you tried grabbing the `book` from the `Author` entity like `@Query("SELECT a.book FROM Author a WHERE a.location = "USA")`

Comment: i want the authors in the same structure as the original Book object, as a list of authors along with the book details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your mapping is **NOT** correct.

You have to fix your `mappedBy` property in the `Book` class.

Book class :

```
public class Book {

    private String bookName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Author> authors;

}
```

Now you can query your database using JPQL to fetch your `Books` and related `Authors`.

Try this in your `BookRepository`:

```
@Query("SELECT b from Book b join fetch b.authors a where a.location = "USA")
```

**PS**: I have not tested the query but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Change your query adding a join,

```
@Query("SELECT a from Book a join a.authors b where b.location = "USA")
```