# How to find record that matches inside List of String in Spring Boot JPA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

There is a list of String in my Database table

```
class Users{
    String userId;
    String userName;
    List<String> bookIds=new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I am using crud reposity  `CrudRepository<Users, String>`. and want to fetch all users who matches bookId.

`List<Users> findByBookIdsContaining(String bookId);`

but i got error **class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.util.List**

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43881272/select-based-on-many-to-one-relationship-criteria-spring-data #Dublicate

Comment: The parameter needs a `List<String>` not a single `String`. Which is what the exception is telling you as well.

Comment: @VictorGubin But I am not using MySql. I am using DynamoDB will it work for it?

Comment: @M.Deinum Yeah , But I want to search that string parameter in List of String . Is it possible by Creating custom method ?

Comment: Again it needs a `List<String>` not a single `String`. You just pass it a List with 1 string in it.

Comment: DynamoDB is not a relational database at all, this is NoSQL solution and not a JPA at all. My advice forget about spring data with DynamoDB, use amazon API directly and read this https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/dynamodb-one-to-many/

Comment: @M.Deinum After passing List<String> as parameter it gives Unable to ''unmarshall exception response with the unmarshallers provided '' exception

Comment: So it basically works and you have an issue in your controller.